# Remove Redundant Data From The Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've the following category table with sample data in sql server:

```
CategoryId      Category         SubCategory    Parent Category
    1         Electronics                             N/A
    2     Computer Accessories   Electronics          N/A
    3           Hardware     Computer Accessories   Electronics
    4           Software     Computer Accessories   Electronics
    5           Clothing                              N/A
    6             Men             Clothing          Clothing
    7            Women            Clothing          Clothing
    8        Food & Beverages                         N/A
```

I am trying to get it as follows without repeating data using `Sql`:

```
CategoryId      Category         SubCategory    Parent Category
    1         Electronics                             N/A
    2     Computer Accessories   Electronics          N/A
    3           Hardware                            
    4           Software     Computer Accessories   Electronics
    5           Clothing                              N/A
    6             Men                               
    7            Women                               Clothing
    8        Food & Beverages                         N/A
```

Basically it's a kind of hierarchy and trying to make it with query. I've to show the category hierarchy in one of the project's web page. So I was trying to do the self-join and retrieve the redundant name once with the following query but stuck:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.CategoryId, 

'Category' = m.CategoryName, 

CASE WHEN m.ParentId = (SELECT TOP 1 ParentId FROM Category q
WHERE q.ParentId = k.CategoryId ORDER BY k.CategoryId) 
THEN k.CategoryName ELSE '' END AS SubCategory, 

'Parent Category' = ISNULL(p.CategoryName, 'N/A')

FROM Category m LEFT JOIN Category k 
ON k.CategoryId = m.ParentId
LEFT JOIN Products o ON o.SubCategory = m.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Category p ON p.CategoryId = o.ParentId
WHERE m.ParentId >= 0
```

It's totally a bad try and hoping to be on the right track with a direction. This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Sample_CategoryList]

Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProductId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [SubCategory] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [float] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Origin] [int] NULL,
    [Stock] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [ProductId], [ProductName], [ParentId], [SubCategory], [Price], [Description], [Origin], [Stock], [Status]) VALUES (1, N'1001', N'ERP Solution Package', 1, 4, 60000, N'', 1, 10, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [ProductId], [ProductName], [ParentId], [SubCategory], [Price], [Description], [Origin], [Stock], [Status]) VALUES (2, N'1002', N'Pendrive', 1, 3, 1000, N'', 1, 10, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [ProductId], [ProductName], [ParentId], [SubCategory], [Price], [Description], [Origin], [Stock], [Status]) VALUES (3, N'1003', N'Denim-Men', 5, 6, 1000, N'', 1, 10, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Products] ([Id], [ProductId], [ProductName], [ParentId], [SubCategory], [Price], [Description], [Origin], [Stock], [Status]) VALUES (4, N'1004', N'Denim-Women', 5, 7, 1000, N'', 1, 20, 1)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [bit] NULL
)

INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (1, N'Electronics', 0, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (2, N'Computer Accessories', 1, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (3, N'Hardware', 2, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (4, N'Software', 2, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (5, N'Clothing', 0, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (6, N'Men', 5, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (7, N'Women', 5, NULL, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [ParentId], [Description], [Status]) VALUES (8, N'Food & Beverages', 0, NULL, 1)
```

**The Main Query**:

```
SELECT m.CategoryId, 'Category' = m.CategoryName, 'Product' = ISNULL(o.ProductName, 'N/A'),
'Sub-Category' = ISNULL(k.CategoryName, 'N/A'), 'Parent Category' = ISNULL(p.CategoryName, 'N/A')
FROM Category m LEFT JOIN Category k 
ON k.CategoryId = m.ParentId
LEFT JOIN Products o ON o.SubCategory = m.CategoryId
LEFT JOIN Category p ON p.CategoryId = o.ParentId
WHERE m.ParentId >= 0
```

**Update - 1**:

[image: sample_output]

**Update - 2** - I tried to handle the hierarchy in the UI using the following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
@foreach (var item2 in lst.GroupBy(p => p.ParentCategory))
{
   <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">

     @if (item2.Key != "N/A")
     {
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#@item2.Key">
             @item2.Key
             <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
        </a>
     }

    </h4>
</div>

 <div id="@item2.Key" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>

      @foreach (var item in lst.Where(p => p.ParentCategory == item2.Key).GroupBy(m => m.SubCategory, (key, c) => c.FirstOrDefault()))
      {
        @item.SubCategory
        <br />
      }

      </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read.

Comment: probably want a recursive CTE here.

Comment: If this is for UI I say do it on the UI.

Comment: Never mind @jarlh. Done it in a hurry.

Comment: @Hogan I was expecting a simple solution. Does it require CTE?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza any better way to do it in the UI I mean little bit confused how to do it in the UI?

Comment: CTE is a simple solution

Comment: AT why hardware get NULL, but software doesnt? How you choose?

Comment: hard to tell exactly what you want -- if it is a tree then you need cte, if all you want is to get blank the first SubCategory and Parent Category when Parent Category is not 'N/A' then all you need is ROW_NUMBER() and a sub-query.

Comment: what that image mean?

Comment: I just wanted to make clear how the hierarchy works in the image sample @Juan Carlos Oropeza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/94b33/12)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT * ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
           (partition by [SubCategory], [Parent Category] ORDER BY [Parent Category]) as rn
    FROM Table1
) 
SELECT [CategoryId], [Category],
       CASE WHEN [Parent Category] = 'N/A' THEN [SubCategory]
            WHEN [rn] = 1  THEN [SubCategory]
            ELSE NULL
       END as  [SubCategory],
       CASE WHEN [Parent Category] = 'N/A' THEN [Parent Category]
            WHEN [rn] = 1  THEN [Parent Category]
            ELSE NULL
       END as  [Parent Category]  
FROM cte
ORDER BY [CategoryId]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| CategoryId |             Category |          SubCategory | Parent Category |
|------------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------------|
|          1 |          Electronics |               (null) |             N/A |
|          2 | Computer Accessories |          Electronics |             N/A |
|          3 |             Hardware | Computer Accessories |     Electronics |
|          4 |             Software |               (null) |          (null) |
|          5 |             Clothing |               (null) |             N/A |
|          6 |                  Men |             Clothing |        Clothing |
|          7 |                Women |               (null) |          (null) |
|          8 |     Food & Beverages |               (null) |             N/A |
```

Comment: order by category id!

Comment: @Hogan you are so strict. :(  .. Done ;)

Comment: Made it work @Juan Carlos Oropeza. Modified your query a little bit and as you suggested, in the UI, finally done. Thanks - See my updated post.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the results but I don't think it is what you want.

```
SELECT CategoryId,
       Category,
       CASE WHEN [Parent Category] = 'N/A' SubCategory
            WHEN [Parent Category] <> 'N/A' AND RN > 1 THEN SubCategory ELSE NULL END AS SubCategory,
       CASE WHEN [Parent Category] = 'N/A' [Parent Category]
            WHEN [Parent Category] <> 'N/A' AND RN > 1 THEN [Parent Category] ELSE NULL END AS SubCategory,
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SubCategory, [Parent Category] ORDER BY CategoryId ASC) AS RN
  FROM table_name_you_did_not_tell_us
)
```

Comment: Did you miss some `THEN` on `= 'N/A' SubCategory` ? Also you don't need check for  `<> 'N/A'` you already pass that case.

Comment: After see your answer I understand your comment better. But OP request isn't clear. Are all rows null except the last one, or just the first one is null. In my case I choose put data randomly on one row and null on all the other.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I made the comment below before I saw this. :D sorry.